# What is an account verification method suitable for a Gmail account used by more than one person?

Tags: gmail, security, authentication, multi-factor-auth

Like many people, I have created a Gmail account that is used by a not-for-profit group I am associated with.  I need to access this account regularly (even though most incoming mail is bounced forward to other addresses).

There are a handful of other people who also need to access the account.  The login details have been shared with those people.

The problems start when someone logs in for the first time using a device Gmail hasn't seen before.  An email goes out to my address (listed as the recovery address), or a TXT goes to my phone (ditto).

A more suitable 2nd-factor authentication method would be a security question whose answer was shared amongst the permitted users, but this has been removed by Google as being apparently not secure enough.

I had thought maybe that responding with "Yes, that was me" would permit access for that device from then on but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Can anyone suggest a way around this?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54638/can-i-use-2-factor-authentication-for-shared-accounts

Answer (score 1):

From [Protect your account with 2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?hl=en)

> **Use backup codes**
>
> **Important**: Never give out your backup codes to anyone.
>
> You can print or download a set of 8-digit backup codes to keep in a safe place. Backup codes are helpful if you lose your phone.

---

IMHO this is Problem X-Y

While it's some sort of common practice to share a Google/Gmail common account that is not a really good idea specially for formal organizations / projects b/c accounts are for individual use (account recovery, account security, etc. are formally designed and operated around this). There are other ways to share content and to collaborate.

If your Non-profit qualify it's better get [Google Workspace for Non-profits](https://www.google.com/nonprofits/offerings/workspace/).